# DataFrame transformation from multiple rows to a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe that looks like (blank transaction IDs belong to ID 1 or ID 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([['1', 'Item1'], ['', 'Item2',], ['', 'Item3'] , ['2', 'Item1'], ['', 'Item2',]]), columns=['TransactionId', 'ProdictName'])
```

[image]

I'm looking for solution how to transform **df** to the new **df1** that doesnt have blanks Transaction IDs, and items are separated by comma:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([['1', 'Item1, Item2, Item3'], ['2', 'Item1, Item2']]), columns=['TransactionId', 'ProdictName'])
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`df.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [15]: df.TransactionId = df.TransactionId.replace('', np.nan) 
In [19]: df.TransactionId = df.TransactionId.ffill()

In [21]: df1 = df.groupby('TransactionId', as_index=False).agg(','.join)

In [22]: df1
Out[22]: 
  TransactionId        ProdictName
0             1  Item1,Item2,Item3
1             2        Item1,Item2
```

**One-liner as per @sammywemmy:**

```
In [26]: df.replace("", method="ffill").groupby("TransactionId", as_index=False).agg(",".join)  
Out[26]: 
  TransactionId        ProdictName
0             1  Item1,Item2,Item3
1             2        Item1,Item2
```

Comment: You can do it in one go ``df.replace("", method="ffill").groupby("TransactionId").agg(",".join)``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks for the info. I was trying to keep it simple for OP to understand. Anyway, I've updated my answer.